# Changing interval of setInterval and all animations are run together

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am dealing with following jquery which contains multiple image animations.My query is, through `setInterval`, my animation is not run step by step and it doesn't maintain interval sometimes. Sometimes my 1st animation and 2nd animation runs together. How can I resolve it and run my all three animation step by step  in specific interval? Can we use `setTimeout`? if yes then how? Please excuse me if I wrote incorrect interval time in  following jquery as I am beginner in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var runAnimate1 = true;
var runAnimate2 = false;
var runAnimate3 = false;

setInterval(function() {
    if (runAnimate1) {
        $("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'margin-left': '220px',
            'margin-bottom': '20px'
        }, 500, function() {
            $('.1st').animate({
                'opacity': '0'
            }, 1000, function() {
                $('.1st').animate({
                    'opacity': '1'
                })
            })
        }).fadeOut();
        $("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({
            'margin-bottom': '0px',
            'margin-left': '-140px'
        }, 1000, function() {
            runAnimate1 = false;
            runAnimate2 = true;
            runAnimate3 = false;
        }).fadeOut('slow');
    }

    if (runAnimate2) {
        $(".2nd").fadeIn('slow').animate({
            'margin-left': '150px',
            'margin-bottom': '2px'
        }, 600, function() {
            $('.1st').animate({
                'opacity': '0'
            }, 1000, function() {
                $('.1st').animate({
                    'opacity': '1'
                }, 1000)
            })
        }).fadeOut();
        $(".2nd").fadeIn('slow').animate({
            'margin-bottom': '0px',
            'margin-left': '-150px'
        }, 1000, function() {
            runAnimate1 = false;
            runAnimate2 = false;
            runAnimate3 = true
        }).fadeOut('slow');
    }

    if (runAnimate3) {
        $('.3rd').fadeIn('slow').animate({
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'margin-left': '220px',
            'margin-bottom': '2px'
        }, 1000, function() {
            $('.1st').animate({
                'opacity': '0'
            }, 1000, function() {
                $('.1st').animate({
                    'opacity': '1'
                })
            })
        }).fadeOut('slow');
        $('.3rd').fadeIn('slow').animate({
            'margin-bottom': '0px',
            'margin-left': '-220px'
        }, 1000, function() {
            runAnimate1 = true;
            runAnimate2 = false;
            runAnimate3 = false;
        }).fadeOut('slow');
    }
}, 6000);
});
```

My html is as follow:

```
<div id="outer-box" class="1st">
<img class="1st" src="img/sofa2.jpg">
<div id="animate1" style="display: none; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;">
    <img class="1st" src="img/chotu.png" style="height:300px; width:200px;" />
</div>
<div class="2nd 1st" style="display:none; position:absolute; bottom:0;   left:0">
    <img src="img/hand.png" style="width:200px; height:300px;">
</div>
<div class="3rd 1st" style="display:none; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0">
    <img src="img/handyh.png" style="width:180px; height: 150px;">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the setInterval in a variable you will be able to change it.

To change the time one possible solution is:

```
var interval = setInterval(functionName,3000);
function changeTime(newTime) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(functionName,newTime);

}
```

Comment: Can I have an example of it?

Comment: I'll try to make one

Comment: How to clear my interval after each animation so that all three animations runs properly.??

Comment: Run `changeTime(newTime)` after each animation. Therefor it will be cleared and set again with a new time.

Comment: Any example using that?

Comment: Can I use setTimeOut?